# How can i fix Invalid Onionsite Address on tor browser?

Tags: linux, browser, kali-linux, tor

I got this message in kali linux - `Invalid Onionsite Address`

The provided onionsite address is invalid. Please check that you entered it correctly.

Details: 0xF6 — The provided .onion address is invalid. This error is returned due to one of the following reasons: the address checksum doesn't match, the ed25519 public key is invalid, or the encoding is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As a client, there is nothing you can do (other than downgrading your browser). That error message means that the site you are trying to reach is using v2 routing, which is no longer supported.

[https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/tor-browser-11-removes-v2-onion-url-support-adds-new-ui/#:~:text=When%20attempting%20to%20open%20a%20V2%20onion%20service%2C,0xF6.%20V2%20Onion%20services%20are%20no%20longer%20supported](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/tor-browser-11-removes-v2-onion-url-support-adds-new-ui/#:%7E:text=When%20attempting%20to%20open%20a%20V2%20onion%20service%2C,0xF6.%20V2%20Onion%20services%20are%20no%20longer%20supported)